# Youtube Data API: Retrieving multiple Video entries by IDs in a single request

Tags: c#, video, youtube

I am wondering if there is a way to query YouTube for multiple random
videos (video id's are known) in a single query?
I am storing video id's in the local db and need to show multiple
details(list with thumbs, rating, author name,etc.) in the web page.

I am looking at the Youtube Data API and see that I can a single
entity data like this:

```
Uri  videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/video_id");
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
```

Repeating this in the loop seems to be a bad idea, because of the
quotas.

There is also "batch processing" available -
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Batch_processing.
Seems like I can issue up to 50 random request, but it expects some
feed I don't have as a parameter, when executing batch.
There is an overload with some Uri, but it is not documented well - google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/docs/folder59/M_Google_GData_Client_FeedRequest_1_Batch__1_2.htm

Does anybody have any ideas on how to retrieve multiple video entries
by id's? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I need to do something similar but to add videos to a playlist. Any info you have would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 11):

In Youtube Data API version 3.0 You can do it in a simple way like this.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=API_KEY&part=snippet&id=video_id1,video_id2
```

Just add your video ids separated by comma. It will fetch you the data for all videos in JSON

I dont know what is the limit on this, will update the answer once I find it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your great help. Apparently I found out that the limit of videos that can be queried is 50.

Comment: Supplement to the above comment: When more than 50 ids are specified, 400 Bad Request is returned with no meaningful error message such as "too many video ids specified".

Answer (score 8):

I too had exactly the same problem, I needed a list of video objects related to an arbitrary list of video id's, i.e. not conforming to any of the feeds.

The batch processing option is very tempting, but the implementation seems quite heavy for what should be pretty simple functionality.

At the end of the day, doing a basic video search for the id's separated by pipe "|" achieves the required result:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=h5jKcDH9s64|elzqvWXG1Y

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for simple solution. looks like there is a maximum of 10 in a query.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work when the ID starts with a dash/ hyphen "-". I encountered this problem and Google confirmed it to me: http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/bc513fd965bcb5ec?pli=1

Comment: To get around the problem with IDs that start with a hyphen, I discovered that you can just remove it! The rest of the ID will match. (This is a hack, not recommended, and probably prone to error...)

Answer (score 4):

RobD's answer works well. You can add something like this to the end of the URL to only retrieve the data you actually need, saving some bandwidth:

&fields=entry(id,title)

eg:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=h5jKcDH9s64|elzqvWXG1Y&fields=entry(id,title)

Comment: Is it possible to restrict the data to get only viewCount and rating? I tried using entry(gd$rating), but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a clearer explanation for the non PHP people

http://oktryitnow.com/?p=83

Comment: Shockingly simple.  Thanks Pickles.  "Post this XML: ... To this URL: ..."  Duh.

Answer (score 1):

You can send multiple requests to youtube data api wrapped in a single request. YouTube allows you to send at most 50 multiple requests in a single request. This kind of request is known as a batch processing request. I have developed a working piece of code specifically for this problem. I had to do same kind of thing for a website I was working on. Anyways you can see how to do it from here (sample code is also present for download): http://www.ovaistariq.net/2010/06/youtube-batch-processing-requests-made-less-costly/