# YouTube API - Get video ratings from list of URLs

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, youtube-api

I have a list of URLs for YouTube videos. I want to use the YouTube API to find the user ratings and rating counts of each of them. The API offers a way to find this information using the URL but only for a single video: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries.

I could send a bunch of synchronous AJAX requests but that is too slow. I tried sending them asynchronously and waiting for them all to finish like so:

```
MyObj.prototype.getYTData = function (urls) {

    var self = this,
        requests = 0,
        vids = [];

    $.each(urls, function (i, vidUrl) {

        var id = self.getURLParameter(vidUrl, 'v');
        requests += 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + id + '?v=2',
            data: { alt: 'jsonc' },
            success: function (data) {

                self.isGood(data.data) && vids.push(data.data);
            },
            complete: function () {
                requests -= 1;
            }
        });
    });

    while (requests) {};
};
```

It seems like the function hangs forever. My guess is it is because I'm flooding the server with too many requests. I could set a small delay between the requests but I think there should be a better way to do this.

What is a good way to get the rating information for all the URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up using setTimeout and jQuery Deferred objects so I could execute code once the requests all finished. Luckily, Stack Overflow already had a [much simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078006/youtube-data-api-retrieving-multiple-video-entries-by-ids-in-a-single-request) that uses a single request.

I ended up doing this:

```
MyObj.prototype.getYTData = function (vidIDs) {

    var IDGroup = $.map(vidIDs, function (id) {
            if (id.indexOf('-') == -1) {
                return id;
            }
            return '"' + id + '"';
        }).join('|');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=' + IDGroup,
        data: { alt: 'jsonc' },
        success: function (data) {

            // Process data
        }
    });
};
```